# Create a scaled secondary y-axis in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics

The objective is to plot a scatter plot and create secondary y-axis. Here, the secondary y-axis is just scaled copy of the original scatter plot.

Assume the scaling can be calculated
y2=y1/2.5

where, `y1` and `y2` is the `y` axis from the scatter plot,and scaled copy of the original scatter plot, respectively.

This can be visualized as below.

[image]

However, using the code below,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x, y = np.random.random((2,50))

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.scatter(x, y*10, c='b')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
y2=y/2.5
ax2.plot(1, 1, 'w-')
ax1.set_xlabel('X1_z')
ax1.set_ylabel('x1_y', color='g')
ax2.set_ylabel('x2_y', color='r')
```

which produced

[image]

There are three issues

- The secondary y-axis is not scaled properly
- As expected but not intended the existence  multiple horizontal line root from the secondary y-axis
- Is there a possible way to create the scaled y-axis without the need of the line `ax2.plot(1, 1, 'w-')`

May I know how to handle this?

Comment: it seems like you don't make use of `y2` in the code. Is this intended?

Comment: Did you try secondary_yaxis?

Comment: @erap129, intended as I dont know the correct way of scale the axis

Comment: Thanks for the idea @JodyKlymak. However, I have issue with the alignment. Appreciate if you can drop by at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69250351/6446053

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, using secondary_yaxis

```
x, y = np.random.random((2,50))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y*10, c='b')
ax.set_xlabel('X1_z')
ax.set_ylabel('x1_y')
ax.set_title('Adding secondary y-axis')
def a2b(y):
    return y/2.5
def b2a(y):
    return 2.5*y
secax = ax.secondary_yaxis('right', functions=(a2b,b2a))
secax.set_ylabel('x2_y')
plt.show()
```

Produced

[image]